# Extract word plus non alpha characters next to it before another word in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to extract the following three occurrences of Books using `preg_match_all()`.

`$input_lines = "Sed ut perspiciatis, **Book  22, 1-3, 3-4. 5.** unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, **Bk. 5, 8-14**, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo (see **BookName 16:1, 6-7, 10-13**) inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem"`

A book is followed by a number followed by comma or colon and optionally many other numbers, separated by commas or numbers separated by dash.  A period is also used to separate sections of the books.

I tried this to get closer:

```
preg_match_all("/(\w+.*?)\w+/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
$input_lines="Sed ut perspiciatis, Book 22, 1-3, 3-4. 5. unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, Bk. 5, 8-14, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo (see BookName 16:1, 6-7, 10-13) inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem";
$regex="/Bo?o?k\.?(?:Name)?[0-9 .:,-]*(?:\d|\.)/";
if(preg_match_all($regex,$input_lines,$output_array)){
    echo "<pre>";
        var_export($output_array[0]);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    echo "No Match";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Book 22, 1-3, 3-4. 5.',
  1 => 'Bk. 5, 8-14',
  2 => 'BookName 16:1, 6-7, 10-13',
)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5AC862/1) & [Code Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9e8d1b34ef3bc1d2cdbc88ae56d574898de3752)

Regex Breakdown:

```
Bo?o?k\.?(?:Name)?     #Matches: "Book", "Bk.", and "BookName"
[0-9 .:,-]*            #Matches: digits, space, dot, colon, comma, and dash (greedily)
(?:\d|\.)              #Concludes matching on digit or dot marking the end of string
```